# Space between data tables while converting into pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

How do I include spaces between data tables while generating a PDF Document with PDFWriter?

This the relevant code snippet:

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("E://sample2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);
    int col = dt.Columns.Count;
    int row1 = dt.Rows.Count;
    int newcol;

    if (col > Convert.ToInt16(txt_columns.Text))
    {
        newcol = Convert.ToInt16(txt_columns.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        newcol = col;
    }

    int k=0, prev=0, dummy=0;
    dummy = newcol;

    for (int num_table = 1, temp = 0; num_table <= ((col / dummy) + 1); num_table++, temp++)
    {
        if (newcol > 0)
        {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(newcol);
            PdfPRow row = null;
            float[] widths = new float[newcol];
            for (int i = 0; i < newcol; i++)
            {
                widths[i] = 4f;
            }

            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            int iCol = 0;
            string colname = "";
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));
            cell.Colspan = newcol;
            int j = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (j > temp * dummy && j <= num_table * dummy)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
                }
                j++;
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (k=prev; k < ((num_table * dummy > col) ? col : (num_table * dummy)); k++)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[k].ToString(), font5));
                    }
                }
            }
            prev = k;

            if (newcol > (col - (num_table * newcol)))
            {
                newcol = (col - (num_table * newcol));
            }
            document.Add(table);
        }
        // need code for gap here
    }
    document.Close();
}
```

The Space is needed at the very end. The poster might use the open source iText library to generate the PDF-document.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to add "space". In the context of tables, you could use something like this:

```
table.SpacingBefore = 5;
table.SpacingAfter = 5;
```

The first line adds 5pts of space before the table. The second line adds 5pts of space after the table.

You could also add a newline. There are different ways to do this:

```
document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE); // the height of the newline will depend on the leading
document.Add(new Paragraph("\n")); // you can define a leading for a `Paragraph`; by default it will be 16pt
...
```

There may be other solutions, but give the ones above a try and let us know which one works best for you.

Comment: Thank you .I need another help how to change back ground and font color of columns and rows in pdf

Comment: That's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434731/dynamic-pdf-row-mockup Also: the StackOverflow policy tells you to post a new question is you have a new question (seems logical, doesn't it?). Do not use comments for further questions.